# How to Get INI file path progrramatically in windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, ini

we write and read ini file from our apps. in win 7 ini file always created in the folder called `"C:\Users\madhabi\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\BBA-reman\BBA Business Assistant (New Part)"`

i know how to get VirtualStore path using code like

```
 String appdata = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            String VirtualStoreRoot = appdata + "\\VirtualStore";
            MessageBox.Show(VirtualStoreRoot);
```

so now i want to get my ini file location progrramatically without hard code anything. so guide me how could i get my ini file path from my apps progrramatically without hard code anything. thanks

Comment: Without some configuration we could be returning any old ini file.

Comment: would u plzz tell me in details what u r trying to say.